# A Way to Change Text After Transition Completes?

Tags: html, css

Dear Stackoverflow readers,

Using only CSS3, is there any way to change the text of a div after the transition is completed?

My code snippet can be viewed here:

HTML

```
<div class="biography">
    <p>Hover For Player Info</p>
</div>
```

CSS3

```
.biography {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #3399FF;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.biography:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px -200px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #7C7C7C;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/6/)

After the transition, I want to change "Hover For Player Info" to "Player Info".

Continuing on that, I need it to change back to "Hover For Player Info" once the mouse is no longer hovering over the div.

If there's no possible way, what skills do I need to learn to achieving what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `what skills do I need to learn to achieving what I want?`
In my answer I used JavaScript language and it's most popular library and probably a must use library called jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.biography').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).html('Player Info');
}, function(e) {
    $(this).html("Hover for Player Info");
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/7/)

Comment: Thank you, I've read your other comment and have some further questions if you don't mind asking.

I have a basic knowledge of JavaScript, I understand the syntax, design theories, and the such.  I have no knowledge of jQuery.  My question is, where do I begin to implement JavaScript (and jQuery) into HTML and CSS?  Is there another website you can lead me to to learn?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Number two: http://jqueryui.com/ (a child plugin for jQuery focusing on inhancing user interface )

Comment: Plain JavaScript, HTML, CSS Reference etc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ Mozilla Developer Network

Comment: I've added the script to my code, however the contents of my div are no longer showing up once I hover (more text and picture isn't displaying).  Can you help me figure this out? [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/13/)

Comment: OK I got it. Thats because on hover function I am setting all the html of the biography class to either player info or hover to view player info

Comment: Oh sorry, my question wasn't asked properly.  This is what I have before adding the JavaScript [JSFiddle Before](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv3Km/).  After adding, the contents disappear as shown here [JSFiddle After](http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/13/).  Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: NOw it's looking awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in CSS alone using `:after`:

```
.biography:after{
    content:'Hover for player info';
}
.biography:hover:after{
    content:'Player Info';
}
```

On `.biograhpy` hover, the content changes, and no JS is required!
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/R9PUQ/18/)

Answer (score 0):

@Tony Hello again. :) I hope your project is going well.

@Faiz has given you a good solution, but it changes the text on hover, not when the animation is complete (as you asked for in your original question).  If his solution works for you, awesome; if you still want the text to change when the transition is complete, here's the code for that below and here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/6vu9F/2/) based off the one Faiz gave above.

```
$('.biography').on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).css('opacity') == 1) { // or any other style from the "hover" form
        $(".player-info-msg").html('Player Info');
    } else {
        $(".player-info-msg").html('Hover for Player Info');
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any problems if you decide to implement this, and let me know if you have any further questions.

EDIT: If you want to read up more on this event, see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend). If you want to know more about jQuery, Javascript, etc. all of the resources @Faiz gave you are great.

Answer (score 0):

Using the onTransitionEnd event helps a lot
Transition and animation have events event attached to dem